# Result of MySQL MAX function

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I'm in trouble understanding how the MAX function works.

Here is my table **MD_board** :

```
idPlayer | matchday | total
---------+----------+-------
    1    |    7     |   354
---------+----------+-------
    2    |    7     |   122
---------+----------+-------
    3    |    7     |   672
---------+----------+-------
    1    |    8     |   452
---------+----------+-------
    2    |    8     |   90
---------+----------+-------
    3    |    8     |   654
---------+----------+-------
```

I want to have the max total and the `idPlayer` of the `matchday` 8. But the query is a mystery to me.

I tried the simple query :

```
SELECT MAX(total), idPlayer FROM MD_board WHERE matchday=8
```

The max value returned is good ( 654 ) but the `idPlayer` is wrong ( 1 ).

I tried a lot of other queries but I'm unable to get the correct result :(

I'm not really comfortable about more complex queries, so, if you could help ...

Comment: What is your expected output from the data above?

Comment: MAX is an aggregate function, it finds the max value of that specific _column_,  it doesn't then return the matching _row_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three `idPlayer`s for `matchday = 8`! You probably use MySQL which allows such wrong queries and you should be aware that the MySQL returns **random** `idPlayer` value. Therefore, you can obtain different `idPlayer` tomorrow than you get today for the same query.

You probably want player with highest `total` in a specific `matchday`:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM MD_board MD1
 WHERE matchday=8 and total = 
    (
         SELECT MAX(total) 
         FROM MD_board MD2 
         WHERE MD2.matchday = MD1.matchday
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it works perfectly.
I'd like to say that idPlayer is not the index. In the table there is also a column ID which is the index and is unique. (i probably shoud have say this before)

Answer (score 1):

Your query:

```
SELECT MAX(total), idPlayer FROM MD_board WHERE matchday=8
```

By applying `MAX` without `GROUP BY` you aggregate your data to one result row. You select the maximum total, which is 654 for that day and *the* idPlayer for the day. But there is no *one* player, it's three different ones. This is invalid SQL according to the SQL standard, but MySQL let's this slip and returns one of the three players arbitrarily.

If you want more data from the record(s) with the maximum total, then select those records again:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MD_board 
WHERE matchday = 8 
AND total = (SELECT MAX(total) FROM MD_board WHERE matchday = 8);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT M.* 
FROM MD_board M
JOIN (
    SELECT matchday,MAX(Total)Total 
    FROM MD_board 
    GROUP BY matchday
    )D on D.matchday=M.matchday AND D.Total=M.Total
```